# VaadinCRM Tutorial Unable to initialize com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I recently started using Vaadin, everything was great for the most part. I created a file merger, and due to a mistake the files endlessly merged until my hard-drive hit capacity.

Now, even when I attempt to run the absolute basic CRM tutorial with no manual changes or adjustments it also no longer runs. So ignoring my application I built, I can't even get the standard CRM tutorial out of the zip file to run. I have attempted **mvn clean install.** I have attempted deleting the generated files and letting them regenerate automatically. I have ran this exact tutorial with no changes mere hours ago and I'm confident there are no malformed characters. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Unless it's a matter of pure coincidence a dependency changed at this exact moment, I must assume spooling my hard drive full ruined something, I just can't figure out what.

```
13:11:31.679 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@38026765
 _____  _                     ____  ____   __  __   _____         _                 _         _ 
|  ___|| |  ___  __      __  / ___||  _ \ |  \/  | |_   _| _   _ | |_   ___   _ __ (_)  __ _ | |
| |_   | | / _ \ \ \ /\ / / | |    | |_) || |\/| |   | |  | | | || __| / _ \ | '__|| | / _` || |
|  _|  | || (_) | \ V  V /  | |___ |  _ < | |  | |   | |  | |_| || |_ | (_) || |   | || (_| || |
|_|    |_| \___/   \_/\_/    \____||_| \_\|_|  |_|   |_|   \__,_| \__| \___/ |_|   |_| \__,_||_|
                                                                                                

2022-03-26 13:11:31.935  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.application.Application      : Starting Application using Java 11.0.10 on DESKTOP-PF37PH2 with PID 5936 (C:\Users\Shane\IdeaProjects\flow-crm-tutorial\target\classes started by Shane in C:\Users\Shane\IdeaProjects\flow-crm-tutorial)
2022-03-26 13:11:31.935  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.application.Application      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-03-26 13:11:31.972  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-03-26 13:11:31.972  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-03-26 13:11:32.379  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-03-26 13:11:32.411  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 26 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-03-26 13:11:32.749  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 80 (http)
2022-03-26 13:11:32.754  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-03-26 13:11:32.754  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.58]
2022-03-26 13:11:32.817  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-03-26 13:11:32.817  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 845 ms
2022-03-26 13:11:32.853  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-03-26 13:11:32.911  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-03-26 13:11:32.917  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:b1ab4f4e-580c-4790-b318-a09826397e86'
2022-03-26 13:11:32.975  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.f.s.VaadinServletContextInitializer  : Search for VaadinAppShell took 6 ms
2022-03-26 13:11:33.519  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.f.s.VaadinServletContextInitializer  : Search for subclasses and classes with annotations took 510 ms
2022-03-26 13:11:33.552 ERROR 5936 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:191) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.lambda$contextInitialized$0(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:213) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:213) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4766) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:478) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at com.example.application.Application.main(Application.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.MissingNode cannot be cast to class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.MissingNode and com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.stats.StatisticsStorage.internalRead(StatisticsStorage.java:149) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.stats.StatisticsStorage.lambda$update$f902d37c$1(StatisticsStorage.java:93) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.stats.StatisticsStorage.access(StatisticsStorage.java:80) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.stats.StatisticsStorage.update(StatisticsStorage.java:92) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.stats.DevModeUsageStatistics.trackGlobalData(DevModeUsageStatistics.java:106) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.stats.DevModeUsageStatistics.lambda$init$30ce3648$1(DevModeUsageStatistics.java:98) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.stats.StatisticsStorage.access(StatisticsStorage.java:80) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.stats.DevModeUsageStatistics.init(DevModeUsageStatistics.java:89) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.initDevModeHandler(DevModeInitializer.java:217) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevModeHandlerManagerImpl.initDevModeHandler(DevModeHandlerManagerImpl.java:80) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener.failFastContextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:474) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:187) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.1.jar:na]
    ... 46 common frames omitted

2022-03-26 13:11:33.552 ERROR 5936 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2022-03-26 13:11:33.552 ERROR 5936 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2022-03-26 13:11:33.554 ERROR 5936 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener]

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener.contextDestroyed(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:491) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.lambda$contextDestroyed$1(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:218) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.contextDestroyed(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:218) ~[vaadin-spring-23.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5477) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:478) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at com.example.application.Application.main(Application.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]

2022-03-26 13:11:33.555  WARN 5936 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.10/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
 java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
 java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
 java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
 java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
 java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11.0.10/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-03-26 13:11:33.556  WARN 5936 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 connection adder] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.10/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
 java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
 java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:458)
 java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1053)
 java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
 java.base@11.0.10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11.0.10/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-03-26 13:11:33.750  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-03-26 13:11:33.753  WARN 5936 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2022-03-26 13:11:33.753  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-03-26 13:11:33.755  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-03-26 13:11:33.761  INFO 5936 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-03-26 13:11:33.777 ERROR 5936 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at com.example.application.Application.main(Application.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:478) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    ... 18 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current problem is related to your previous hard-drive capacity problem.

It should be solved by deleting the following file in your home directory `.vaadin/usage-statistics.json`

You can find a recent bug report here https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/13362

Comment: I'm going to expand on this suggestion with the final result that fixed the problem. I went to .vaadin located in C:\Users\Username\.vaadin
I moved this folder (renamed to vaadinold) and magically we are up and running again. I tried messing with the individual file as you suggested but that didn't seem to work.